# What does binding mean exactly?

Tags: c++, python, binding

I always see people mention that "Python binding" and "C Sharp binding" etc. when I am actually using their C++ libraries. What does binding mean? If the library is written in C, and does Python binding means that they use SWIG kind of tool to mock a Python interface?

Newbie in this field, and any suggestion will be welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When someone talks about something like a "C# binding" of a library, they are indicating that you and API is being provided in C# for a library written in a different language. This may or may not involve an autogeneration tool like SWIG.

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes. A binding is just that, an *interface* to a library or program written in another language, though it need not be generated using SWIG.

SWIG is just a tool for *automatic* generation of the same...

Answer (score 0):

You're right, for a general library, a "binding" essentially means "easily callable from". The binding may or may not have been created with SWIG, that's just one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

> If the library is written in C, and
>   does Python binding means that they
>   use SWIG kind of tool to mock a Python
>   interface?

Yes, you are right. That will be called a Python binding of the respective library.